# Apply transformation to a Numpy vector using values in other vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 1D Numpy array `t` (say of length `len_t`) containing values I want to apply a certain mathematical transformation. Along this, suppose I have 4 1D Numpy arrays `a1`, `k1`, `k2` and `d`, all of same length (say `len_p`).
The mathematical transformation I want to apply to `t` involves all these parameters. Therefore, I want to end up with a Numpy array of shape `(len_p, len_t)` containing transformed values of `t` transformed using each values of `a1`, `k1`, `k2` and `d` one by one. For more precision, the transformation I want to apply is
`y = (a1*(t - d)*k1)/(k2+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t - d))`
where `l1` is a simple float. I did not precise indices not to overweight notation. If my explanation is unclear, please tell me.
Does anybody have an idea on how I should proceed? I do not show more code as I will proceed to other similar transformations in the future and therefore need a general method.

EDIT

As an example, let us say

```
t = [0 1 2]
```

and

```
a1 = [.5 .1]
k1 = [.01 .3]
k2 = [.7 .03]
d = [.2 .41]
l1 = 2
```

What I want to get is a 2D array such that each row contains `t` values transformed by a set of parameters having the same indices in `a1`, `k1`, `k2` and `d`. Therefore, the output would be

```
y = [[(a1[0]*(t[0] - d[0])*k1[0])/(k2[0]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[0] - d[0])) (a1[0]*(t[1] - d[0])*k1[0])/(k2[0]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[1] - d[0])) (a1[0]*(t[2] - d[0])*k1[0])/(k2[0]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[2] - d[0]))]
[(a1[1]*(t[0] - d[1])*k1[1])/(k2[1]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[0] - d[1])) (a1[1]*(t[1] - d[1])*k1[1])/(k2[1]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[1] - d[1])) (a1[1]*(t[2] - d[1])*k1[1])/(k2[1]+l1)*np.exp(l1*(t[2] - d[1]))]]
```

So, with numerical values, it goes

```
y = [[(.5*(0 - .2)*0.01)/(.7+2)*np.exp(2*(0 - .2)) (.5*(1 - .2)*0.01)/(.7+2)*np.exp(2*(1 - .2)) (.5*(2 - .2)*0.01)/(.7+2)*np.exp(2*(2 - .2))]
    [(.1*(0 - .41)*.3)/(.03+2)*np.exp(2*(0 - .41)) ((.1*(1 - .41)*.3)/(.03+2)*np.exp(2*(1 - .41)) (.1*(2 - .41)*.3)/(.03+2)*np.exp(2*(2 - .41))]]
```

Comment: the `len_t` and `len_p` are equal?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: so what's the meaning of `t - d`, can you write some example?

Comment: I just gave a simple and short example. Of course, lengths are far greater in typical applications.

Comment: Are you familiar with [broadcasting in NumyPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)? If you just add an extra second axis to each of your four `len_p` arrays it should suffice (i.e. like `a1 = a1[:, np.newaxis]`, `k1 = k1[:, np.newaxis]`, etc., then apply your formula).

Comment: Yes !! It does exactly what I want ! Thank you very much ! I think this is much more efficient than a for loop !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your variables to *Numpy* arrays:

- *t* - to "ordinary" (row) array,
- all other - to  **columnar** arrays (something like you used *np.newaxis*
  in the simplified expression):

The code to do it is:

```
t  = np.array(t)
a1 = np.c_[np.array(a1)]
k1 = np.c_[np.array(k1)]
k2 = np.c_[np.array(k2)]
d  = np.c_[np.array(d)]
```

Then run your simplified expression:

```
y = (a1 * (t - d) * k1)/(k2 + l1) * np.exp(l1 * (t - d))
```

To compare both results (yours and mine) run `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` before.
Otherwise the results would be printed in "exp" notation, what impedes
comparison. You may also adjust *precision* option.